# DragonFire SDK Access violation

Tags: iphone, visual-studio-2010, access-violation, dragonfire-sdk

I started testing DragonFire SDK, looking into the example apps that come with it.
Everything works fine until I try to close the app in any other way then shift+F5.

Then I get an access violation:

> Unhandled exception at 0x002bdb38 in MyFirstApp.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Everything is fresh out of the box and I haven't done anything to it.

Does anyone know how to fix this?